# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - package org.netbeans.lib.awtextra does not exist

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception, awt

Whenever I am trying to compile my java project in netbeans IDE, I am getting these errors. Kindly, please help me through it. I have provided the whole source code as well. Thank you
the error are given below. I am making a car parking system in java and my whole source code in written in java language

```
>Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - illegal start of expression
at NewParking.initComponents(NewParking.java:211)
at NewParking.<init>(NewParking.java:30)
at NewParking.lambda$main$0(NewParking.java:425)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)

**CODE**:The code for my program is given below.

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author 7386-85615SG 2913642
 */
public class NewParking extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Connection conn;
PreparedStatement pst;
ResultSet rs;
    /**
     * Creates new form NewParking
     */
    public NewParking() {
        super("Parking");
        initComponents();
        conn=javaconnect.ConnecrDb();
        getTrackNo();
        String a="<html><u>NAMASTE- WELCOME TO OUR PAGE-SWAGATAM</u></html>";
        jLabel10.setText(a);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jDateChooser1 = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jDateChooser2 = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), 4, true));

        jComboBox1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Select", "Hyundai", "Honda", "Mahindra", "Maruti", "Tata", "Skoda", "BMW", "Rolls Royce", "Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "Aston Martin", "Land Rover", "Jaguar", "Nissan", "Yamaha", "Hero Honda" }));

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 32)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setText("Full Name");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 32)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Gender");

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 32)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("RC no.");

        jTextField4.setEditable(false);

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 32)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("Parking Issue");

        buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton2);
        jRadioButton2.setText("Male");

        buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton1);
        jRadioButton1.setText("Female");

        jTextField2.setEditable(false);

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 32)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Brand");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 32)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Position");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 32)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Parking Expiry");

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 32)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setText("Track Number");

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 32)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setText("Slot No.");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 289, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 289, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 289, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 289, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 289, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 289, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 289, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 289, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 289, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 23, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                                .addGap(127, 127, 127)
                                .addComponent(jRadioButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 164, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 594, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1)
                            .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 505, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jDateChooser1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 511, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jDateChooser2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 511, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 594, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(43, 43, 43))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 594, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap())))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jRadioButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jRadioButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 101, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(30, 30, 30))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(8, 8, 8)))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(11, 11, 11)))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 58, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jDateChooser1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(73, 73, 73)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(90, 90, 90)
                        .addComponent(jDateChooser2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(94, 94, 94)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(???, java.awt.Color.red, java.awt.Color.black, java.awt.Color.blue, java.awt.Color.yellow));

        jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 3, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton4.setText("BACK");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 3, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton5.setText("CLEAR");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 3, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("PARK");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 284, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 159, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 159, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 159, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sylfaen", 3, 62)); // NOI18N
        jLabel10.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 0, 204));
        jLabel10.setText("NAMASTE- WELCOME TO OUR PAGE-SWAGATAM");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(148, 148, 148)
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGap(218, 218, 218))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addContainerGap())))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(143, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(53, 53, 53)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(321, 321, 321))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1368, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(88, 88, 88))))
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jTextField2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jTextField4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
  // TODO add your handling code here:
    }  
       private void getTrackNo()
{
    try
    {
    String sql="select * from laps where status='"+str+"'";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                String add1=rs.getString("lapn");
                jTextField2.setText(add1);
                String add2=rs.getString("trackn");
                jTextField4.setText(add2);
            }
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("getTrackNo. Error=+ex");
    }finally{
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("getTrackNo. Error=+ex");
    }
        }
}
       public void updateData()   //protocol= jdbc odbc=sub protocol//
{
try
{
 String a1=jTextField2.getText();
 String a2=jTextField4.getText();
pst=conn.prepareStatement("update laps set status='"+str2+"' where lapn='"+a1+"' and trackn='"+a2+"'");
pst.executeUpdate();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
System.out.println("Error in insert"+ex);

}
}
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
          try{
            String sql="insert into Registration (rc,name,gender,position,brand,issue,expiry,lapn,trackn) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
            pst.setString(2, jTextField3.getText());
            
            jRadioButton2.setActionCommand("Male");
            jRadioButton1.setActionCommand("Female");
            pst.setString(3, buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand());
            
            pst.setString(4, jTextField5.getText());
            pst.setString(5, (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
            pst.setString(6,((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            pst.setString(7,((JTextField)jDateChooser2.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            pst.setString(8, jTextField2.getText());
            pst.setString(9, jTextField4.getText());
            pst.executeUpdate();
            updateData();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Car Parked");
        }catch(HeadlessException | SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      setVisible(false);
        Login ob = new Login();
        ob.setVisible(true);
          // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jTextField1.setText("");
        jTextField3.setText("");
        jTextField5.setText("");
        jTextField2.setText("");
        jTextField4.setText("");
        ((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).setText("");
        ((JTextField)jDateChooser2.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).setText(""); // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewParking.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewParking.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewParking.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewParking.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new NewParking().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser jDateChooser1;
    private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser jDateChooser2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    // End of variables declaration                   
String str="AVAIL";
String str2="RESERVED";
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a `???` in the generated code that won't compile.

Comment: @Kayaman Thank you for helping me. Indeed it was the error.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error tells you that there is a problem on line 211 that causes compilation to fail. That line is this:

```
jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(???, java.awt.Color.red, java.awt.Color.black, java.awt.Color.blue, java.awt.Color.yellow));
```

You'll notice ??? as the first argument, which is causing this compilation failure.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createBevelBorder(int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.Color)) the '???' is in place of a `type` argument which should be either `BevelBorder.LOWERED` or `BevelBorder.RAISED`. So, maybe it will work if you change the above line to

```
jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, java.awt.Color.red, java.awt.Color.black, java.awt.Color.blue, java.awt.Color.yellow));
```

Comment: Hey!!!
Thank you so much for the answer. Can you please tell me how to resolve this error? I am highly indebted to you.

Comment: @HemangJoshi I haven't used that function, but it looks from the docs like your '???' is replacing what should be an argument `type`, which is either BevelBorder.LOWERED or BevelBorder.RAISED. I will add a potential fix in my answer.

Comment: Hello Sir. It worked properly. I edited it as BevelBorder.RAISED and **it finally compiled without any errors**. I am currently 6 reputations short to upvote the answer, but my feedback has been recorded and it will update accordingly. I am just a rookie in java programming but I aim to be proficient like you. Thank you for helping me to overcome this error. Have a wonderful year ahead sir.